# laravel vagrant setup problems with encoding

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I'm getting this error 
[image: error]

after trying to run vagrant box add laravel/homestead.

I have followed almost all tutorials how to fix it but it didn't help..

I'm using windows 8.1(x64), and I have special characters inside the name of my user account(á,š) but I haven't installed anything inside the folder with some "special" characters.

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest telling Vagrant to use a folder other than your User's home folder to store downloaded boxes.

You can do this by setting the VAGRANT_HOME environment variable.  For instance I have it set to E:/vagrant/data.

Comment: I had to create a new user and install it there